# mysqldbcopy: command not found

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a script that requires usage of the [mysqldbcopy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqldbcopy.html) tool. From reading the [ubuntu manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mysqldbcopy.1.html), it appears that one just needs to install the mysql-utilities-1.3.5-1_all. When entering that into `apt-get install`, it could not be found, so I tried using the mysql-utilitie* regexp which resulted in the following output:

```
Note, selecting 'mysql-utilities' for regex 'mysql-utilitie*'
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

This leads me to believe that I already have it installed.

The output of `mysql --version` for reference is:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

What do I need to do in order to get mysqldbcopy installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop?

Answer (score 2):

check the dpkg installed packages:

$> dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql-utilities

if you see the mysql-utilities packet installed it IS INSTALLED!
if not do a

$> sudo apt-get install mysql-utilities

then

$> sudo updatedb

$> sudo locate mysqldbcopy

if you get to much results?! then try to grep:

$> sudo locate mysqldbcopy | grep bin
....

maybe it's not in your path?
i think it should be at /usr/bin/mysqldbcopy

Comment: Thanks for this, it turns out you were correct in that it was not installed. I tested by uninstalling mysql-utilites, and then running the original commands again with the same results. Unfortunately `sudo apt-get install mysql-utilities` (e.g. no regexp) did not work for me with the message `Package mysql-utilities is not available, but is referred to by another package....`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that one needs to [manually download that specific package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/mysql-utilities), after choosing your specific architecture, fixes the issue. I guess that these are additional tools that are not installed through the `mysql-utilities` package. I made sure to use the "release" version, rather than "proposed".